# Grouping users help

Tags: 7, organic-groups

I'm building an application where a group of users interact with customers...however for each user in a group he/she has his own customers. I also need the ability to having 1 user with his/her own customer...meaning this user is not a part of any group. Should I use Organic group for this or would vanilla drupal work just fine (with taxonomy and roles?). Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think Users can also be Organic Groups in Drupal 7, as everything related to OG are just fields now which can be attached to anything. So that might be something you could try.

Not sure what kind of communications you have in mind, but if it is meant to be private, maybe a combination of [User Relationships](http://drupal.org/project/user_relationships) and [Privatemsg](http://drupal.org/project/privatemsg) could get you started. Those modules can be integrated so that only related users can send each other private messages.

Comment: Oh thank you for your reply. The relationship is between a manager and one of his workers. One bothersome issue is I don't want to use the same signup form for managers and workers. For example, a worker that works for Manager A should just see a dropdown of managers to select from when he signs up, but when a manager signs up (say the first manager - Admin) he needs to create the group, say Group A. Now a manager and worker will have different signups..I'm not sure if I'm clear...but I'd like to hear your response.